# Programming an EPROM using 8085 kit

Tags: programming, programmer, eeprom, ram, 8085

I need to program an EPROM/EEPROM with the code for an 8085. I do not have a programmer. I can't buy one. But I have access to an [8085 kit](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:8085-8086Microprocessor.jpg). Can I use it to program the EPROM/EEPROM via an interface? What difficulties may I expect if I do it this way?

Comment: RAM generally doesn't get burned.

Comment: Ok! Changed 'burn' to 'program'.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to program EPROMs with the 8085 kit. I used to use a Z80, it was quite easy. You shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: It doesn't get programmed either. It's volatile.

Comment: Thanks @LeonHeller ! I need to finish my assignment project soon and wanted to know if I could do it this way.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams : I meant I wanted to store a program in the RAM temporarily. Can I do it using 8085?

Comment: It will vanish as soon as you disconnect power.

Comment: Yes, I know that. Just wanted to know whether I could use the 8085 kit instead of a programmer.

Comment: Your question makes no sense to me. A 8085 can of course write to the RAM that is connected to its bus! Writing to EPROM or EEPROM depends on the particular chip, and might vary from 'writing to RAM, but only slower' to 'needs a precisely times pulse of some weird voltage'.

Comment: I wish to know how difficult it would be to write to the EPROM/EEPROM. I shouldn't have mentioned RAM in the question, I think! I'm editting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually those kits include a monitor program and some kind of battery-backed RAM.

You are going to have to find an instruction manual and read it however, since you will need access to instructions and such like. If you read the manual, then you probably won't need to ask the question, so I guess RTFM (Read The Fine Manual) is the only possible answer.

[Here](http://www.educationaldidactictrainers.com/8085-microprocessor-trainer-kit-1.php) is a typical such board, and the blurb states:

8K bytes of Powerful Monitor Program using 27512 EPROM
8K bytes of RAM using 6264 with Battery Backup using NICD Battery

So if that was the one you had, and you had the manual, you should be able to use the monitor program to load a user program into battery-backed RAM and execute it. The monitor may do some trickery like modifying your code to insert breakpoints for debugging, so do read the manual.